# need help converting c to c++ (simple error but cant fix)

Tags: c++

I have a c++ homework. The homework is asking to convert a c program to c++.
Below is the question:

> You are requested to convert the following C function into a C++
>   function and then embed it into a complete program and test it. Note
>   that this function copies a binary file of integers and not a text
>   file. The program must accept the arguments (the file to copy and the
>   file to be copied to) from the command line.

```
/* ==================== cpyFile =====================

This function copies the contents of a binary file
of integers to a second file.
Pre fp1 is file pointer to open read file
fp2 is file pointer to open write file
Post file copied
Return 1 is successful or zero if error
*/
int cpyFile (FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
  /* Local Definitions */
  int data;

  /* Statements */
  fseek (fp1, 0, SEEK_END);
  if (!ftell (fp1))
  {
    printf ("\n\acpyFile Error : file empty\n\n");
    return 0;
  } /* if open error */
  if (fseek (fp1, 0, SEEK_SET))
    return 0;
  if (fseek (fp2, 0, SEEK_SET))
    return 0;

  while (fread (&data, sizeof (int), 1, fp1))
    fwrite (&data, sizeof (int), 1, fp2);
  return 1;
} /* cpyFile */
```

I did my best and managed to convert it, but unfortunately when I'm using it , the file that I get after the copy is empty.  Below is my answer:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
  if(argc!=3)
  {cerr<<"invalid number of arguments. must be 3."<<endl;exit(1);}

  fstream fp1(argv[1],ios::in);
  if(!fp1)+{cerr<<argv[1]<<" could not be opened"<<endl;exit(1);}

  fstream fp2(argv[2],ios::out);
  if(!fp2)+{cerr<<"file could not be found."<<endl;exit(1);}


  int data;

  fp1.seekg (0,ios::end);
  if (!fp1.tellg ())
  {
    cout<<"\n\acpyFile Error : file empty\n\n";
    return 0;
  } /* if open error */
  if (fp1.seekg (0, ios::beg))
    return 0;
  if (fp2.seekg (0, ios::beg))
    return 0;

  while (fp1.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof (int)))
  {
    fp2.seekp(0);
    fp2.write (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof (int));
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I did my best and everything is working fine, except that when I copy a binary file, the file that i get is empty and I have no idea why.

Comment: A good attempt, I commend you for giving it a decent go rather thank simply asking someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Don't do this on your homework, but for future reference: `std::ofstream(argv[2]) << std::ifstream(argv[1]);`

Comment: Why do you have `fp2.seekp(0)` *in* the loop?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Didn't you forget a `.rdbuf()` on your `ifstream`?

Comment: @celtschk: I've been told that's not needed.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Is that a C++11 change?

Comment: @celtschk: No, I've seen that code around forever.  I've never actually used it though.  Could be that I was mistaken.

Comment: @MooingDuck: At least g++-4.3.2 doesn't like it (I tried it with explicit variables, so it's not just an rvalue reference problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode, as others have said, by doing

```
fstream fp1(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary); // combine ios::in with ios::binary

fstream fp2(argv[2], ios::out | ios::binary); // combine ios::out with ios::binary
```

Or you can make them `ifstream` (*in file stream* for reading only) and `ofstream` (*out file stream*, for writing only) and remove the `ios::in` and `ios::out` because `ifstream` implies `ios::in` and `ofstream` implies `ios::out`:

```
ifstream fp1(argv[1], ios::binary);

ofstream fp2(argv[2], ios::binary);
```

You need to do this because if you don't, the file will be translated when you read from or write to it for things like turning line endings from `\r\n` or `\r` to just `\n`, etc, which will mess up your binary data which may happen to have those bytes in them.

This:

```
if (fp1.seekg (0, ios::beg))
    return 0;

if (fp2.seekg (0, ios::beg))
    return 0;
```

Will always make your code return because `seekg` returns the object you call it on. It's not the equivalent of `fseek` in this regard because `fseek` returns 0 on success. So you never get to the `while` loop. Take those out of the `if` statements so  that it looks like this:

```
fp1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
fp2.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Or if you have to have the checking, you want to do

```
if (!fp1.seekg (0, ios::beg)) // notice the added !
    return 0;

if (!fp2.seekg (0, ios::beg)) // notice the added !
    return 0;
```

Also, this (inside the `while`):

```
fp2.seekp(0);
```

Is setting the point you are going to write to to the beginning of the file. So you'll never write anything but at the beginning of the file. Just remove that line completely.

<strike>Also, you have a `return` inside the loop which makes it return on the first iteration. Move the `return 1;` outside the loop so you only return after the loop is finished.</strike> Nevermind that, misread due to the unusual brace style.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you read a new data block from `fp1`, you rewind `fp2` to the beginning of the stream, essentially discarding what you have already written to `fp2`. Try moving `fp2.seekp(0)` out of your main loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems. I'd start by fixing this bit:

```
if (fp1.seekg (0, ios::beg))
    return 0;
if (fp2.seekg (0, ios::beg))
    return 0;
```

The `seekg` method returns a reference to the `istream` it's called on, so the above is equivalent to this:

```
fp1.seekg (0, ios::beg);
if (fp1) // i.e., if fp1 is in a valid state (as opposed to e.g. end-of-file)
    return 0;
fp2.seekg (0, ios::beg);
if (fp2) // i.e., if fp2 is in a valid state (as opposed to e.g. end-of-file)
    return 0;
```

which is obviously not what you want.

To debug your code, you can use statements like `std::cout << "Got to line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;` to figure out which parts of the program are actually being run. That would have found the above problem pretty quickly.

Comment: Don't forget about `__LINE__`: `cout << "Got to line " << __LINE__ << endl;` :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Stolen, thanks. ;-) I'd started to suggest a different sort of message (`"Got to the ____ while-loop"`), and then only half-migrated to the line-based approach before posting. :-P

Comment: Debug statements like these are useful for small programs; a lot of people always say "learn to use a debugger", but the truth is, everyone at this stage already knows how to use print statements so for the time being it is probably more productive to do so. Ultimately, learning how to use a debugger is an invaluable skill, but sometimes it's just easier to put a `printf` or `cout` in than set up breakpoints, watch variables, etc. etc.

Comment: @dreamlax unless you have an IDE like VS, which makes breakpoints easier than just about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Binary files need to be opened specifically in binary mode, so where you have `fstream fp1(argv[1],ios::in);` you should also add an ios::binary to it like so: `fstream fp1(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);`

Answer (score 0):

In the C++ code you are seeking to the beginning of the output file before writing each number, and therefore the output file will be at most 2 bytes long.

Comment: It will be *at least* 2 bytes long. The `int` type can be any size as long as it is greater than or equal to 2 bytes.

Comment: @dreamlax You are right. I guess for me it's time to go to sleep